# Use position dodge for arrowheads but nudge_x for label boxes in ggreppel::geom_text_repel

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to use `ggrepel::geom_text_repel` to annotate a figure in `ggplot`, but can't seem to figure out how to get my desired outcome. I'm using a `position_dodge()` for my x-axis, and would like to both adjust the position of the labels along the x-axis so that they don't overlap with the error bars, but also to `position_dodge` the arrow heads so they continue to point at the correct place on the error bars. The problem is I can only seem to be able to do one or the other.

For example:

```
data = structure(list(effect_type = c("indirect effect [a*b]", "indirect effect [a*b]", "direct effect [c']", "direct effect [c']", "total effect [c'+(a*b)]", "indirect effect [a*b]", "direct effect [c']"),estimate=c(-0.0143997565527918,-0.00758421890501637,0.0871582661676552,0.0939738038154307, 0.0795740472626389, -0.0109919877289041, 0.090566034991543), ci.high = c(-0.029931151113111, -0.0205775872487205,-0.010462274428183,-0.0026775225700392,-0.0157731542618071,-0.0216430527477706,-0.00682426319942687), ci.low = c(0.000198738920234162, 0.00512543538602775,   0.188025123198128,0.195696995423836,0.181851768399776,-0.00134616814440178,0.19136163736259),p=c(0.054,0.224,0.08, 0.062, 0.118, 0.022, 0.074), cond_med_level = c("english","dutch", "english", "dutch", "not_applicable", "average","average")), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")


 pd = position_dodge(.2)

 ggplot(data,aes(x=effect_type,y=estimate,color=cond_med_level)) +
        geom_point(position=pd) +
        geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=ci.low,ymax=ci.high),width=.1,position=pd) +
        geom_hline(aes(yintercept=0),color='blue',linetype='dashed',size=.5) + 
        geom_label_repel(aes(label=paste("p = ",p,sep="")),
                         nudge_x=.5,
                         force=1,
                         size=4,
                         show.legend=FALSE)
>>>
```

[image]

Here the labels are nicely nudged to the side, but the arrow heads aren't dodged.

```
ggplot(med.out.del.plot,aes(x=effect_type,y=estimate,color=cond_med_level)) +
        geom_point(position=pd) +
        geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=ci.low,ymax=ci.high),width=.1,position=pd) +
        geom_hline(aes(yintercept=0),color='blue',linetype='dashed',size=.5) + 
        geom_label_repel(aes(label=paste("p = ",p,sep="")),
                         box.padding = 2.5,
                         force=20,
                         size=4,
                         show.legend=FALSE,
                         position=pd)
>>>
```

[image]

Here the arrowheads point nicely to the correct error bar mean point, but the labels look terrible and overlap the error bars. Obviously I've tried calling both `nudge_x` and `position` but that fails with `Error: Specify either position or nudge_x/nudge_y`. Any help appreciated.

Comment: It might help to specify `direction = "x"` inside of `geom_label_repel`, not a full answer to your question but it looks much cleaner to me

Comment: Yeah, I've played with that... As you say, not a full answer. But thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's too bad that there is not an elegant solution to solving the issue of needing to "dodge" and "nudge" at the same time.  You need `position=` to dodge without question, so all that is left to move the labels around is to use `direction='y'` (to only allow the labels to spread out in the y direction) and set limits with `xlim=` to where they can go.  In essence, we want to tell the labels "stay on this side of the datapoints, and far enough away so you don't mess with my errorbars!"

The approach here is that you need multiple `geom_label_repel` calls.  I use a `for` loop to step through each level, and since the "numeric" position of a discrete axis = the position of the level of that factor, we can programmatically "shift" the `xlim=` term according to each factor to be an area just to the right of the center point of the factor.

```
# set your x axis term as a factor so we can steal those levels
data$effect_type <- factor(data$effect_type)
subset.effect <- levels(data$effect_type)

# base plot object
p <- ggplot(data,aes(x=effect_type,y=estimate,color=cond_med_level)) +
  geom_point(position=pd) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=ci.low,ymax=ci.high),width=.1,position=pd) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=0),color='blue',linetype='dashed',size=.5)

# add individual geom_label_repel objects for each level
for (i in 1:length(subset.effect)) {
  p <- p + geom_label_repel(
    data=subset(data, effect_type==subset.effect[i]),
    aes(label=paste("p = ",p,sep="")),
    position=pd, force=1, size=4,
    direction = 'y',
    xlim=c(i+0.2, i+1),
    show.legend=FALSE)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, too bad there isn't a more elegant way: you would think it is a common enough use case that there might be. Nonetheless, a great solution. Cheers.